# Which Algorithm to choose in pattern matching time serie?

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching, design-patterns

I 've got multiple time series represented as multiple list of integers (in main memory, not in database). I need to perform a fast search, among all series, to find a specific pattern.

Example, detect the pattern `[ (0,1), (3,2), (4,1) ]` where (x,y) x = time, y = # series.

I've googled for pattern detection, pattern matching, but it seems there are thousand of algorithms, and I don't quite see the relation with my problem most of the time. 
I could do the first idea whose coming to my head, like ,for every point,checking the distance to the next point on specific train according to the pattern, and so on.

I need directions on where to start, because i'm confused among all theses researcher publications !

Thank you very much

Nico

Specification : I will make multiple pass, with a jitter associated. 
for example, let's take the pattern define above. For the first pass, I'll need to match exact pattern. The second pass, I will need to match the pattern with a jitter of one ->
[ (0,1), ( 3 +- 1, 2) (4 +- 1, 1) ], second pass -> [ (0,1), (3 +- 2, 2) (4 +- 1, 1) ] etc. Jitters go up to five.
Only the first "event" (time,# serie) is "constant" at all time.

I also need to add the fact that the maximum time in the time series are around 100 000, so it may be converted into a "bit string" of 0 and 1s.

EDIT : The VALUE at a specific time doesn't matter, I don't even have it. It just a series of "event" at different time & position (which serie the event is on). All events are equal. (papers sometimes detect patterns which has double value etc etc, but here it s useless)

Comment: Do you need an approximate match, or just exact matches?

Comment: I've added a more detailed specification :)

Comment: In addition to searching for "pattern matching," try also searching for "querying" or "indexing" of time series data, which produces e.g. [this paper](http://www.cse.uconn.edu/~dqg/papers/cp95.pdf), [this paper](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~drafiei/papers/sigmod97.pdf), and [this thesis](http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/udbl/Theses/HenrikAndreJonssonPhD.pdf).

Comment: Also are you looking for speed, or just anything that works?

Comment: Speed is Critical,memory usage doesn't really matters.It is for a scientific program.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to use a state machine to represent the problem? Like (0,1) can be a state and from there, you can expect the next state, based on the "turn" variable.

Comment: Can you develop a little bit more ? what is your "turn" variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a review of many Subsequence Time Series Clustering algorithms in

> Zolhavarieh, S., Aghabozorgi, S., & Teh, Y. W. (2014). A Review of
>   Subsequence Time Series Clustering. The Scientific World Journal,
>   2014, 1–19. https://doi.org/10.1155/2014/312521